# Face recognition in offline videos

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am looking for tools to recognize faces in several mp4 files. I stumbled upon the opencv library but I was hoping that somebody might have written some example code that I could check out or point me to some other tools.

The task is as follows: I have a set of about 600 people with lots of training images. I would like to know whether these people appear in my set of several dozen mp4 videos (usually, about 50-100 appear in each video).

Thx

Comment: New OpenCV has a `FaceRecognizer` class. There are detailed tutorials and sample code, you can search and see if it suits you.
FaceRecognizer [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html)
Tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_save_load.html) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use Python and openCV than you need to do a small research about scanning mp4 files and using openCV libs to find your faces. from here you just need to count.
if you will google it you will find it.
hope its helped you.